# How to save state of fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am using four fragments in one activity
Four buttons at bottom are used to switch between fragments
I have search button of action bar
But when i am clicking on search button keyboard appears and then after that fragment started loading again..
So how to save state of fragment on configuration change..
I have also tried this

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`public void setRetainInstance (true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) in **fragment**.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        ...
        ...
    }
```

> This will retain only when there is change in orientation, not on back stack.

Comment: where to write this line  onCreate() or onCreateView()??

Comment: How are you switching between fragments ?

Comment: RestaurantsFragment rf = new RestaurantsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction().addToBackStack("category");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("cat_id", arrayList.get(position).getCatId());
    args.putString("cat_name", arrayList.get(position)
      .getCategory());
    rf.setArguments(args);
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, rf);
    ft.commit();

Answer (score 0):

You can use setRetainInstance(true). No matter where you write - in onActivityCreated or OnCreateView. But in this case you can have problems with memory or link on old Activity in future.
As for me, I think that it's better to save your data in onSaveInstanceState and get them, for example, in onRestoreInstanceState.